# Error running Glassfish 3.1.2.2: Address localhost:4848 is already in use

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, glassfish, port

I have installed my glassfish on port 4848, then I have a test project in IntelliJ IDEA that contains `.jsp` files which I want to run on glassfish.I've read a tutorial on how to run an application on glassfish via IntelliJ [here](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_GlassFish_Server), but when I do the job I get the following error:

```
Error running Glassfish 3.1.2.2: Address localhost:4848 is already in use
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error you are getting it seems that a glassish instance is already running on that port and IntelliJ is trying to start up a new one. Did you start your glassfish instance via command line? Maybe you could try starting it up with IntelliJ and see if that works better ...

Answer (score 2):

On S.O. Windows: in console you input `netstat -ano` and you see the port and service's ID. Then you input `taskkill /pid numberIDService` or `taskkill /f /pid numberIDService`

Answer (score 1):

it could be not only glassfish, u could check which application is using port 4848. To do that u should enter "netstat -ao" in your cmd to find that proccess and delete it. Then try again to run glassfish

Answer (score 1):

On Linux based OS,

```
sudo lsof -i:4848
sudo kill <PID>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your cmd as administrator
2. Type Following commands as follows.

```
netstat -ano | findstr :4848
taskkill /PID 27372 /F
```

Note: I know the person who put this has already got the answer long time ago. This is for the new comers like me, a clear solution for windows user.